# IntelliJ IDEA Creating a ton of new windows when I try to run my code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm making a very simple program in IntelliJ. It's going smoothly, and I would still be making progress if it ran properly. I click the run button and it gives me no errors when compiling, but it opens a ton of windows very quickly, and when I stop the program it closes them all. This has effectively halted my progress and I'm starting to run out of time to complete this. Anyone have a fix?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    public String output;
    public String input;

    public GUI() {
        panel = new JPanel();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("Input");
        label.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
        panel.add(label);

        JTextField inputText = new JTextField(20);
        inputText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
        panel.add(inputText);

        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        outputLabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        panel.add(outputLabel);

        JTextField outputText = new JTextField();
        outputText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        panel.add(outputText);

        JButton button = new JButton("Convert");
        button.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        button.addActionListener(new GUI());
        panel.add(button);

        JLabel successLabel = new JLabel("");
        successLabel.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(successLabel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        input = inputText.getText();
        output = outputLabel.getText();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to give us a lot more than that. Then we can try and help. You sound like a student and are new to IDEA, perhaps Java? Have you changed any configuration besides setting a JDK? What OS are you on? What version of IDEA? What type of application are you running and how are you running it? Does your application have a GUI, and if so, is it possible you are creating windows in a loop? Can you please post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: First off, thank you for helping me. Second off, I am a student and new to the IDEA, yes I'm writing in Java, and I haven't changed anything besides the JDK(14). I'm using Windows 10, I'm using IntelliJ version 2020.2.1(community edition). Yes, my program has a GUI. I'm writing a program to convert units of measurement between each other and I'm currently testing the GUI part in a single class with a main method, but that will soon be phased out.(continued in next comment)

Comment: I may be creating windows in a loop, but the problem started when I made an edit to my code(I don't remember what) and was not occurring before that. I have posted my code in the original question as I am confused about the meaning of reproducible example. Thank you for taking the time to help me, and I apologize for posting what seems to be a poorly written question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. See my answer.

Comment: A late-in-the-game tip for when you forget what code you changed. You can click on almost any entry in the Project toolbar (classes, packages, etc...) and use the "Local History" feature to view the last 5 days of changes before the last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for updating your post with the code. You have, in fact, created an endless loop!

The problem lies with:

```
button.addActionListener(new GUI());
```

You are creating a new instance of the class `GUI` every time the class `GUI` is instantiated. See what I mean?

I think you want to use the current instance of class `GUI` as your action listener, so the correct way to do this would be:

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

Hope that helped.